# Why python can't find libavcodec.so.54 after Ubuntu update from 14.10 to 16.04?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I've update from Ubuntu 14.10 to 16.04 yesterday and right now I've tried to run my old python + opencv files but every file with opencv gives the same error:

```
python blendImages.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blendImages.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: libavcodec.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

you know some workaround this?

Comment: Update cv2 which is linked against an old version of libavcodec (part of ffmpeg project). Recompile the library

Comment: how do i recompile it?

Comment: Well, acutally this depends on how did you do it before. The most common way to install and update [custom] python modules on user level (not system-wide) is to use [pip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/installing/index.html), which takes care of all aspects.

Comment: I've installed it just with
sudo apt-get python-opencv

Comment: Have you updated the package? What version do you have installed right now?

Comment: Yep, i did.
Python 2.7.11+
and
python-opencv_2.4.9.1

Comment: Ok. I've checked, the only opencv-related package which requires libavcodec.so.54 is libopencv-highgui2.4. Make sure that you have updated it to libopencv-highgui2.4v5 from Xenial

Comment: it says  libopencv-highgui2.4v5 is already installed :/
can you give me a short guide how to completely remove and newly install it on 16.04?

Comment: Well, the basic tool is `apt` in console. `apt purge <smth>` to remove a package, `apt install <smth>` to install it. But first make sure that there's no _old_ libopencv-highgui2.4. I guess it's somehow loaded, either from a package, or from a local build, not registered in the package system.

Comment: i've looked for that older version but can't find one... instead i've seen that ffmpeg has a newer version of libavcodec
`libavcodec 56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100`
`purge` and `install`didn't work either...

Comment: I'm having the same problem after upgrading to 16.04. I'm so sorry I upgraded!!

Comment: I got the same problem. @CitrusPunk did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may help if you install these packages.

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
```

and FFmpeg as well.

Comment: Installing of FFmpeg worked best. Here's a what worked for me https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg